# Nhibernate how to get rid of proxies and have the concrete when reference is loaded

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have Item with 1:m relation to TreeNode.
TreeNode has refernce to parent node ... and has reference to another Objects.

TreeNode and his relation are stored in second level cache.

**My problem:**
If i use the default lazy than these TreeNode will be loaded from second level cache if i travel on the parent.

**But**
It will be loaded as a proxy and i have to have it as concrete class (i call to function on this Object and association more than 2000 times).

**If i set lazy=false on the TreeNode class def:**

Than hibernate will load all the reference of its in the join and i will not have benefit from the second level cache.

**Can i define that object will be loaded as concrete andassociation of it when loaded (by call the association) also will be loaded as concrete?**

Thank you

Comment: Is there really a measurable performance impact of the proxy?

Comment: FYI, the proxy will only go to the db once, not once for each time you access it.

Comment: The problem is not the DB. its the overhead in proxy. and when you have thousands of call this has impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want a proxy put lazy=false on the class level or crate a clone on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need it to be a concrete class?

In any case, here's how to get the unproxied instance: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html

Comment: I am looking for mapping solution. I dont want to traverse on each reference unproxy it and set the value to the reference.

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano: you didn't answer my question.

Comment: In the application the property of these objects will be called more than 7K for each property on each request (please dont ask me why :) ), so in this case call on proxy or concrete has significate effect.

Comment: @AvihaiMarchiano: 7K virtual calls are still in the millisecond realm. Do you have any profiling data supporting the "significant effect" claim?

Comment: Yep, this is 7K calls for each property (4 properties) it sums to around 30ms. The castle proxy add overhead of intercept and reflection.

Answer (score 0):

See if lazy="no-proxy" as explained by Ayende Rahien in the following blog post works for you:

[NHibernate New Feature: no-proxy associations](http://ayende.com/blog/4378/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations)